# Getting error Too many re-renders when using useState to assign match.params value to it

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props, use-state

This is the segment of my code which is causing problem.

```
function CreateU(props) {
const [uid, SetUid] = useState('');
const { id } = props.match.params;
  if (typeof (id) !== 'undefined') {
    SetUid(id);
  }
.
.
.
}
```

I am getting error Too many re-renders.
And I can't use id directly for the sake of reusability of the component,
I need to assign it to uid.
I also need to check for undefined because in some cases I don't pass id in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CreateU(props) {
  const [uid, SetUid] = useState('');
  const { id } = props.match.params;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof (id) !== 'undefined') {
      SetUid(id);
    }
  }, [id])

  .
  .
  .
}
```

You need to wrap your call to state setter in a `useEffect` Hook. Otherwise you end up in an endless loop, you're updating state on render, which triggers a rerender and another state update and so on.